# Leaflet iconurl using global variable

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to make my iconurl a global variable (or any variable, called var1), but it doesn't seem to work. The code is below. Note that when iconurl is set to 'http://www.our.server.com/picture', the code works, but if we set var1='http://www.our.server.com/picture' and then do iconurl: var1 (as done below), it does not. I checked in the console and var1 is correct (we also use this link/variable elsewhere successfully).

```
var myIconData = L.Icon.Label.extend({
options: {

iconUrl: var1,
shadowUrl: 'images/marker2.png',

iconSize:     [40, 40], // size of the icon
shadowSize:   [50, 55], // size of the shadow
iconAnchor:   [20, 50], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
shadowAnchor: [25, 55],  // the same for the shadow
popupAnchor:  [0, -55], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor

labelAnchor: [0, 0],
wrapperAnchor: [20, 50],
labelClassName: 'sweet-deal-label'
}
});
```

how we call the marker (which works):

```
mymarker=new L.Marker([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude],{ 'icon': new myIconData(), 'title': username });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be elsewhere.

You can use a variable: see by yourself here http://franceimage.github.io/leaflet/7/

```
// custom icon
var image = 'leaf-green.png'; 
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: image,
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
```

I have also tried with a http form (but I would not advise for it)

did you check your javascript console when you have the problem ?

Comment: I tried doing the following: {iconUrl: 'www.ourserver.com/picture/' + username}. This ends up showing the picture at 'www.ourserver.com/picture/', which means that username is null, but it is not null when i print it (it is correct when printed to the console) since i make sure that (along with the console), the function cannot run, since it is in an if statement like: if (username != null){ function with iconurl...}

Comment: A friend looked over my code and we found the problem. Basically, I didn't realize that myIconData is a global variable as well (the way I have the code), and so is var1. Therefore var1 is null when myIconData is made (and switching their order doesn't matter since var1 is made in another function). Every time I perform (in L.marker) the following: 'icon': new myIconData(), I am merely making a new copy of myIconData, when var1 was null. This is also why when setting var1 = 'some string' it works. If I put in more information you (FranceImage) would have probably figured it out. Thanks.